# Java Web application architecture discussion

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications, architecture

I come from a Java background and work in web development since a few years. Because I didn't learn web development from scratch my skills grew but aren't as clean and solid. The java web application I'm talking about is about 8 years old and was created by developers who were no experts of web development. Result: they/we did a lot of the stuff which you never should do. Because we want to renovate our application in the next few years I want to try to find a clean strategy/architecture.

Our System works like that: Server (not Webserver) stores a lot of different objects with totally different structures and does a lot of data analysis based on a data warehouse system. Through sockets a client is connected to the server. One client is a j2ee web client. We have Servlets, Actions, JSPs, Beans... We have to much business logic in the client which will be moved to the server. Our software is highly configurable and grew pretty big. Because the views can be changed dramatically by the calculated data, its state and so on our JSPs are far to complex with too much scriptlets - not good.

What I thought of:

- Every controlling action/business logic will be moved to the server.
- The server sends back the data with meta data so the client can manage the view fast without doing validations and stuff like that on its own. (e.g. meta tag 'invalid')
- The client between the servlet and the server creates the HTML code with the help of a template engine like Freemarker or Mustache.java.
- This HTML code will be responded to replace, fill or add a DOM node.
- We will use Ajax requests.

What do you think about this approach? Any hints about weaknesses or flaws? Would using a webservice instead of a servlet make sense?

So right now I'm not looking for a framework (but please don't hold back if there is one you have to mention) but for the general architecture I want to use in the future.

Thank you in advance for advise and hints.

---

It seems like my description of our current structure was a bit confusing. Second try:
Our software started as a non web application. We have a server which manages the data, calculations, ... The connected clients render the view and fetch the user interaction. About 8 years ago my company decided to develop a web application for the client. An instance of our client (which holds the connection to the server) is stored in the session and can be accessed by the servlets, jsps etc. So the webserver actually is a part of the client in our system.

I hope this helped.

Comment: "The client between the servlet and the server"?  "Our System works like that: Server (not Webserver)..."?  What is this server that's not a webserver that requires you to have a "client" between the webserver and the server?  You really need to explain this.

Comment: I edited the post, hope it's not as confusing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways I might do it, depending on what your homegrown TCP/IP server actually returns and how much of a hassle it is to deal with. Without knowing all the particulars its hard to know which is best.

Option 1 (Leave TCP/IP server alone, and redevelop webapplication only):

1. Think of the homegrown TCP/IP server as more or less an improvised database server, and leave it as is. That is, I wouldn't touch it, at all.
2. I would leave the application logic in the webapplication but move it out of JSPs into Servlets. Basically, rewrite the webapplication part to separate views (JSP) from logic (Servlets).
3. I'd use JSP for the HTML templates, and fill them in with Ajax requests to the Servlets where the logic is. (Or, use the Servlets as controllers that set request attributes and forward to JSPs, without the users ever seeing .jsp in the address bar.) The Servlets would in turn access the homegrown TCP/IP server in much the same way a normal Servlet would access a database server.

Option 2 (unify the systems into one, redesign it all as just a webapplication):

1. Move all code from  homegrown TCP/IP server to Servlets in the webapplication, and get rid of homegrown TCP/IP server. No point in having two servers.  If you're investing the time to rewrite this mess, rewrite it as one system.
2. I would leave the application logic in the webapplication but move it out of JSPs into Servlets. Basically, rewrite the webapplication part to separate views (JSP) from logic (Servlets).
3. I'd use JSP for the HTML templates, and fill them in with Ajax requests to the Servlets where the logic is.  (Or, use the Servlets as controllers that set request attributes and forward to JSPs, without the users ever seeing .jsp in the address bar.)

OR, Option 3 (replace TCP/IP server with cronjobs, to populate a db to drive the webapplication):

1. Change the homegrown TCP/IP server into something that runs constantly in the background of a server (rather than something that must be called by a client). It could be something like a Windows Service written in C#.net, or a set of java console programs scheduled in Linux using cronjobs. It would populate some kind of database to be used by the webapplication.
2. Make the webapplication only read that database. No need for it to access the server thing anymore.
3. Same stuff about separation of view and logic, etc.

Option 4 (replace TCP/IP server with webservices):

1. Replace the homegrown TCP/IP server with a webservice or set of webservices.
2. Same as option 1.
3. Same as option 1, except now you're accesing a webservice from the Servlets rather than an old-school TCP/IP server.

Comment: We will definitely go with option 1 because the server is so big that would take about 2 years for three developers to rewrite it. Right now I'm more focused on the web application side which will contain less logic in the future. It will basically be an interface to the server. My problem is, I see our JSPs and see where they led us. They are stuffed with if/els, switches, ... So we have about 100 different JSPs in our application. I want to get rid of that complexity in the JSPs. So is my approach (HTML in Servlets) foolish?

Comment: If you are out.print()ing whole pages in Servlets that's a bad idea. It will get even messier than the JSPs, especially if you have to include Javascript. You'll end up with a bunch of escaped quotes that will make your eyes glaze over. But to me it makes sense for a small snippet of HTML, like if you have a Servlet that returns a snippet of HTML to an Ajax request to fill a DIV.

Comment: Yes I'm worried about this, that's the reason I asked this question. Well that's what I was thinking of: Using a template engine like FreeMarker to create templates/snippets (similar to jsp), combine them in the servlet as needed ad resend them with Ajax. So instead of using jsp:includes which would create a mess in the jsps because I would have to check (in the jsps) which jsp with which params I had to include, I would move this code (of deciding which template will be used with which params) to the servlet or a utility class.